# Como modifico los atributos de un input, que ha sido creado por medio de una respuesta de ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5, ajax

Estoy tratando de modificar los atributos de un input que genero dinamicamente y que muestro en la pagina por medio de ajax.

```js
function traigo_form(){
    $.ajax({
        data:{enviado: true}   
        type: "POST",
        url: "localhost/miproyecto/traer_form.php",
        success: function(data){
            $('#formulario').html(data);                
        }
    });
    $("#valor").attr("type","hidden");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="traigo_form()" id="boton" value="traer"></button>
<div id='formulario'>

</div>
```

```
<?php
if($_POST['enviado']){
    $formulario="<form>
    <input id=\"nombre\" type=\"text\">
    <input type=\"text\" id=\"valor\">
    </form>";
    echo $formulario;
}
```

Comment: ¿Que problemas estás teniendo? ¿Tienes algún error? Deberías de añadir algo más de información.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function traigo_form()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            data:{enviado: true}   
            type: "POST",
            url: "localhost/miproyecto/traer_form.php",
            success: function (data)
            {
                $('#formulario').html(data); 
                $("#valor").attr("type","hidden");               
            }
        });

  }
```

Como la gracia de Ajax es su naturaleza asíncrona, el cambio del atributo se debería realizar en la función `success`